# Wicket, modify HTML <body> element

Tags: java, html, twitter-bootstrap, wicket

I want to modify the HTML body tag when I open a Wicket-Bootstrap `Modal`. What I'm trying to achieve is `<body class="modal-open">` instead of `<body>`

Using Wicket 8 M8 , I have this code:

```
owsImportDialog = new MyModalBootstrapDialog("owsImportDialog"
        , new CompoundPropertyModel<>(new BopOwsTO()))      {

    @Override
    void importOws(AjaxRequestTarget target, IModel<BopOwsTO> owsModel) {
        appendCloseDialogJavaScript(target);
        BopOwsTO owsTo = owsModel.getObject();
        try {
            importOwsCapabilities(owsTo);
            owsViewDialog.header(Model.of("OWS anzeigen"))
                    .setModel(Model.of(owsTo.getServiceId()));
            owsViewDialog.appendShowDialogJavaScript(target);
        }
        catch (OwsCapsImportException e) {
            String localizedMessage = e.getLocalizedMessage();
            importAlert.setModelObject(localizedMessage);
            importAlert.appendShowDialogJavaScript(target);
            error(localizedMessage);
        }
        finally {
            target.appendJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]" +
                  ".setAttribute('class', 'modal-open');");
            // target.appendJavaScript("document.body.setAttribute('class', 'modal-open');");
            // target.prependJavaScript("document.body.setAttribute('class', 'modal-open');");

            // target.appendJavaScript("alert('Hallo');");

            // owsViewDialog is a child of owsView WebMarkupContainer
            target.add(owsView, feedback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    void saveOws(AjaxRequestTarget target, IModel<BopOwsTO> owsModel)
    { }
    @Override
    void cancel(AjaxRequestTarget target)
    { }
};
```

If the line `target.appendJavaScript("alert('Hallo');");` is active I actually see the alert window.

I also tried this code in the page class:

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(response);
    PackageResourceReference resourceReference = new PackageResourceReference(
            getClass(), "../css/BuiOwsPage.css");
    CssReferenceHeaderItem cssRef = CssReferenceHeaderItem.forReference(resourceReference);
    response.render(cssRef);
    response.render(OnLoadHeaderItem
            .forScript("document.body.setAttribute('class', 'modal-open');"));
}
```

But none of my attempts was succesful.

**Update**
The answer of @martin-g didn't solve the issue.
I'm quite sure that the problem is caused by the sequence of these statements:

```
{
    appendCloseDialogJavaScript(target);
    ...
    try {
        owsViewDialog.appendShowDialogJavaScript(target);
        ....
    }
    catch { ... }
    finally {
        target.add(owsView, feedback);
    }
}
```

When `this` modal is closed because of `appendCloseDialogJavaScript()` ,
the class `modal-open` is erased from the `class` attribute of the `<body>` .
Then `owsViewDialog` opens, but `modal-open` **isn't** inserted in `class`, no matter if I append the snippet `jQuery(document.body).addClass('modal-open')` or not. The missing `modal-open` means that the page can't be scrolled.

Comment: Your `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].setAttribute('class', 'red');` should work. Is there an `iframe`? It would have its own `document`. Also, how do you check that the class does not change? Visually or by using an element inspector in your browser?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy - I don’t use an `iframe`. I’ve used the Chrome developer tool to check if the class `modal-open` is present in `<body>` , and the behavior of my Modal isn‘t as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Since Wicket and Bootstrap are used then jQuery is also available. I would recommend you to use `jQuery(document.body).addClass('modal-open')`.

There must be a reason why jQuery has both addClass() and attr()!